# Function that takes an input between 0 and 5 and outputs an array of 5 elements that will be used for generating 5 stars in the UI

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking for a solution to this problem, I need to put a number between 0 and 5 inclusively and it must output an array of 5 elements,
For example, if I put 5 I must get [100, 100, 100, 100, 100]

Examples:
createStars(3.5) // [100, 100, 100, 50, 0]
createStars(1.6667) // [100, 66.67, 0, 0, 0]

This is my attempt at it

```js
function numberStars(number) {
  var array = [];
  if (number > 0 && number <= 5) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var multiplied = number * 100;
      remainder = multiplied % 100;
      array.push(remainder);
      multiplied = remainder;
    }
  }
  return array;
}
```

it gives back [60, 60, 60, 60, 60]

Comment: So you calculate the number you need to get to 3.5/5 * 500 and you start looping

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 1):

For a JavaScript solution, create an array of size 5 for the output. Then loop through every index. If the given number is larger than the current index, output 100. If the number minus the index is between 0 and 1, then output the decimal part times 100. If none of those conditions are true, then output 0.

```js
function createStars(n) {
  const output = Array(5);
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let num = n - i;
    if (num >= 1) output[i] = 100;
    else if (num >= 0) output[i] = num*100;
    else output[i] = 0;
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(createStars(3.5));
console.log(createStars(4.7)); // The only reason that this is [100,100,100,100,70.00000000000001] is because of floating point precision errors
```

A TypeScript solution would be the exact same, except just with added typedefs.

```js
function createStars(n: number): [number, number, number, number, number] {
  const output: [number, number, number, number, number] = [0,0,0,0,0];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let num = n - i;
    if (num >= 1) output[i] = 100;
    else if (num >= 0) output[i] = num*100;
    else output[i] = 0;
  }
  return output;
}

console.log(createStars(3.5));
console.log(createStars(4.7)); // The only reason that this is [100,100,100,100,70.00000000000001] is because of floating point precision errors
```

Answer (score 0):

You could multiply the wanted value with `100` and take a minimum value or `100` for mapping and subtract this value from the wanted result.

```js
function createStars(v) {
    v *= 100;
    return Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => {
        const r = Math.min(v, 100);
        v -= r;
        return r;
    })
}

console.log(...createStars(3.5));    // [100, 100, 100, 50, 0]
console.log(...createStars(1.6667)); // [100, 66.67, 0, 0, 0]
```

And here's a TypeScript solution, which is just the JavaScript solutions with added typedefs.

```js
function createStars(v: number): number[] {
    v *= 100;
    return Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => {
        const r = Math.min(v, 100);
        v -= r;
        return r;
    })
}

console.log(...createStars(3.5));    // [100, 100, 100, 50, 0]
console.log(...createStars(1.6667)); // [100, 66.67, 0, 0, 0]
```